# user sessions expires unexpectedly irrespective of the time mentioned in the config settings in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, config, session-timeout

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 525600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

this is my config setting but the session is expired after two or 3 hours .
is there any solution for this?
ci version 3.1.8 and php version 7.2

Comment: please add CI version and php version

Comment: ci version 3.1.8 and php version 7.2

Comment: I'd suggest to upgrade to CI 3.1.11, there where some session related problems reported in earlier versions.

Comment: than you !changed the ci verion and it worked  ..